# Cassandra 1.2 using symbolic link for /var/lib/cassandra/data

Tags: cassandra

I thought this would be simple. I guess not.

I have an external hard drive mounted at `/root/storage` - OK
I moved the data directory from `/var/lib/cassandra/` to `/root/storage` - OK
I then created a symbolic link out of `/var/lib/cassandra` pointing to where the directory is now.....so...... `ln -s /root/storage/data /var/lib/cassandra` - OK

Now I am unable to start cassandra. I am getting this error in `/var/log/cassandra/system.log`:

> INFO [main] 2013-02-15 10:08:36,329 CacheService.java (line 166)
>   Scheduling row cache save to each 0 seconds (going to save all keys).
>
> ERROR [main] 2013-02-15 10:08:36,366 FileUtils.java (line 373)
>   Stopping the gossiper and the RPC server ERROR [main] 2013-02-15
>   10:08:36,367 CassandraDaemon.java (line 387) Exception encountered
>   during startup java.lang.IllegalStateException: No configured daemon
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:314)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.handleFSError(FileUtils.java:375)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.(Directories.java:113)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.Directories.create(Directories.java:91)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.scrubDataDirectories(ColumnFamilyStore.java:403)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:174)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:370)
>           at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:413)
>   [root@cassandra-new6 storage]# vi
>   /usr/share/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra.yaml

The permissions are exactly the same on this directory.  All file permissiosn are teh same too.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

When I get rid of the sym link and move the data directory back, everything works again.

Comment: Shouldn't the symbolic link be to the /root/storage directory instead of the /root/storage/data directory?

Comment: I don't believe so. I moved data directory itself out of /var/lib/cassandra and onto /root/storage/. I believe the symbolic link will be ln -s /root/storage/data /var/lib/cassandra

Answer (score 4):

The symlink regression is fixed in Cassandra 1.2.2. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5185

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating a sym link, you can change where Cassandra looks for the data directory in the cassandra.yaml file by changing the data_file_directories parameter.

Comment: Changed the data_file_directories parameter in my cassandra.yaml file and am still getting the same error in both system.log and cassandra.log, refer to the output below.

Comment: ERROR 08:00:51,396 Stopping the gossiper and the RPC server
ERROR 08:00:51,397 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No configured daemon